# Why can't I compare tuples of arbitrary length in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I know that there are predefined `Eq` instances [**for tuples of lengths 2 to 15**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978389/haskell-tuple-size-limit).

Why aren't tuples defined as some kind of recursive datatype such that they can be decomposed, allowing a definition of a function for a  `compare` that works with arbitrary length tuples?

After all, the compiler does support arbitrary length tuples.

Comment: And how exactly do you see a "decomposed" tuple?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Like `head` and `tail` on lists. Why can't there be such functions for tuples?

Comment: because lists are homogenous, i.e. all their items are of the same type. Tuples on the other hand contain different types, that's why you can't even compare tuples of the same arity, if their items differ, because `compare` requires same types, i.e. you can't compare `(Int, Bool)` with `(Int, Int)`.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Tuples with the same type have equal length and equal element-types, therefore, one can compare these tuples, but there are only implementations up to length 15. What I'm wondering is, why one can't make one function that works for any length.

Comment: Regarding your last line, I don't think GHC supports arbitrary length tuples: [`GHC.Exts` defines a constant `maxTuples` for probably that reason.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Exts.html#v:maxTupleSize) On my machine it's 62.

Comment: Not haskell, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621559/n-ary-tuples-vs-pairs

Comment: The apologist in me wants to ask "What the heck do you need 16-tuples for? Just use a real type already!".

Comment: @DanielWagner Why do you need filenames longer than 8 characters? Just use more folders. I'm trying to understand why Haskell has these seemingly artificial limitations, that's all.

Comment: @Odin, I think it was an unfortunate early design choice that we're stuck with.  Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978389/haskell-tuple-size-limit/2978450#2978450

Answer (score 10):

You might ask yourself what the type of that generalized comparison function would be.  First of all we need a way to encode the component types:

```
data Tuple ??? = Nil | Cons a (Tuple ???)
```

There is really nothing valid we can replace the question marks with.  The conclusion is that a regular ADT is not sufficient, so we need our first language extension, GADTs:

```
data Tuple :: ??? -> * where
    Nil  :: Tuple ???
    Cons :: a -> Tuple ??? -> Tuple ???
```

Yet we end up with question marks.  Filling in the holes requires another two extensions, DataKinds and TypeOperators:

```
data Tuple :: [*] -> * where
    Nil  :: Tuple '[]
    Cons :: a -> Tuple as -> Tuple (a ': as)
```

As you see we needed three type system extensions just to encode the type.  Can we compare now?  Well, it's not that straightforward to answer, because it's actually far from obvious how to write a standalone comparison function.  Luckily the type class mechanism allows us to take a simple recursive approach.  However, this time we are not just recursing on the value level, but also on the type level.  Obviously empty tuples are always equal:

```
instance Eq (Tuple '[]) where
    _ == _ = True
```

But the compiler complains again.  Why?  We need another extension, FlexibleInstances, because `'[]` is a concrete type.  Now we can compare empty tuples, which isn't that compelling.  What about non-empty tuples?  We need to compare the heads as well as the rest of the tuple:

```
instance (Eq a, Eq (Tuple as)) => Eq (Tuple (a ': as)) where
    Cons x xs == Cons y ys = x == y && xs == ys
```

Seems to make sense, but boom!  We get another complaint.  Now the compiler wants FlexibleContexts, because we have a not-fully-polymorphic type in the context, `Tuple as`.

That's a total of five type system extensions, three of them just to express the tuple type, and they didn't exist before GHC 7.4.  The other two are needed for comparison.  Of course there is a payoff.  We get a very powerful tuple type, but because of all those extensions, we obviously can't put such a tuple type into the base library.

Comment: "because of all those extensions, we obviously can't put such a tuple type into the base library." GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, and FlexibleContexts. Perhaps someday (soon? one can dream) they will be integrated into the definition of Haskell.

Comment: To maintain the same strictness behavior that tuples have, I think you'd want to have `Cons` be strict in its second component (`Cons :: a -> !(Tuple as) -> Tuple (a ': as)`).  Given `data T = T`, there are five values in `(T,T)`: `⊥`, `(⊥,⊥)`, `(T,⊥)`, `(⊥,T)`, and `(T,T)`.  However, `Tuple '[(),()]` has the extra four values `Cons _ ⊥` and `Cons _ (Cons _ ⊥)`, where `_` can be either `()` or `⊥`.  Also, it's worth noting (for searchability) that `Tuple` is also known as a heterogenous list (or hlist).

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm not sure we actually need either `TypeOperators` or `DataKinds` for this. Antal's point about strictness is also significant.

Answer (score 8):

You can always rewrite any n-tuple in terms of binary tuples.   For example, given the following 4-tuple:

```
(1, 'A', "Hello", 20)
```

You can rewrite it as:

```
(1, ('A', ("Hello", (20, ()))))
```

Think of it as a list, where `(,)` plays the role of `(:)` (i.e. "cons") and `()` plays the role of `[]` (i.e. "nil").  Using this trick, as long as you formulate your n-tuple in terms of a "list of binary tuples", then you can expand it indefinitely and it will automatically derive the correct `Eq` and `Ord` instances.

Comment: I understand that I can do that, but the question is: Why doesn't Haskell work like that internally? That's just what I meant by "recursive datatype".

Comment: n-tuples were originally defined to avoid the gratuitous lifting that recursively nested binary tuples would entail.  Unfortunately, this was an unwise decision because we cannot go back and fix it.  If you were to retroactively define n-tuples this way you would break a lot of type class instances for n-tuples that would now overlap with the instance for binary tuples.

Comment: What exactly does `gratuitous lifting` mean? So the bottom line is: It's that way because of legacy reasons?

Comment: One thing to note is that nested tuples have more places that can be bottom. An unnested tuple can only have bottom for the entire value or for a particular element. A nested tuple can have bottom for any of its "tails".

Comment: Dan Burton explained the lifting part.  We say that a type is "lifted" if it can be inhabited by bottom.  With an n-tuple you can only have one bottom for the entire tuple, but with nested tuples you can have one bottom per nesting level.

Comment: @DanBurton I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I think of a nested tuple just like list: `x : xs`, but for tuples. How could there be multiple tails except for `xs`?

Comment: @Odin I wrote up a few lines of code to illustrate: http://hpaste.org/81794 . "bottom" or `undefined` represent erroring (e.g. divide by zero) or nonterminating (e.g. infinite recursion) computations.

Comment: This was not an unwise decision. n-tuples are just _different_ than heterogenous lists. We have both, we can use both, but there's no reason that the formulation you give in this answer is everywhere superior to the other.

Comment: @sclv, I am unconvinced.  Supposing history went a different way and we never got tuples (but we got its notation), what would we miss?

Answer (score 2):

A type of `compare` is [`a -> a -> Ordering`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3acompare), which suggests that both of the inputs must be of the same type. Tuples of different arities are by definition different types.

You can however solve your problem by approaching it either with [HLists or GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections).

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I meant to ask. I'm not sure how to clarify further.

Comment: IIUC, @Odin was asking about comparing two tuples of *the same* (arbitrary tuple) type.

Comment: @Conal see Odin's comments under his question

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to ertes' answer that you don't need a single extension to do this. The following code should be haskell98 as well as 2010 compliant. And the datatypes therein can be mapped one on one to tuples with the exception of the singleton tuple. If you do the recursion after the two-tuple you could also achieve that.

```
module Tuple (
    TupleClass,
    TupleCons(..),
    TupleNull(..)
    ) where

class (TupleClassInternal t) => TupleClass t

class TupleClassInternal t
instance TupleClassInternal ()
instance TupleClassInternal (TupleCons a b)

data (TupleClassInternal b) => TupleCons a b = TupleCons a !b deriving (Show)

instance (Eq a, Eq b, TupleClass b) => Eq (TupleCons a b) where
    (TupleCons a1 b1) == (TupleCons a2 b2) = a1 == a2 && b1 == b2
```

You could also just derive Eq. Of course it would look a bit cooler with TypeOperators but haskell's list system has syntactical sugar too.